# Dynamic programming with memorization in python

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to write a code that checks if a word can be *"broken"* into a combination of words in a certain list. For an example, if my input is:

```
word = 'strawberryfield'
list = ['straw', 'berry', 'field']
```

Then the program should return `True`.

The code I managed to write is:

```
class Solution(object):
    def wordBreakInner(self, s, wordDict, memo):
        # print("entered with: ", s)
        
        if s in memo:
            return memo[s]
        
        if len(s) == 0 or s in wordDict:
            memo.append(s)
            return True
        
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if s[0:i:1] in wordDict:
                # print("found this word in dict: ", s[0:i:1])
                if s[i:] in memo:
                    return true
                else:
                    if self.wordBreakInner(s[i:], wordDict, memo):
                        memo.append(s)
                        return True
        return False
        
        
    def wordBreak(self, s, wordDict):
        """
        :type s: str
        :type wordDict: List[str]
        :rtype: bool
        """
        return self.wordBreakInner(s, wordDict, [])
```

It seems working but it cannot handle long input. That's why I tried adding the memoization handling (not sure if I did it very well). For the following input, the program time limit exceeds:

```
word = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab'
['a', 'aa', 'aaa', 'aaaa', 'aaaaa', 'aaaaaa', 'aaaaaaa', 'aaaaaaaa', 'aaaaaaaaa', 'aaaaaaaaaa']
```

Can somebody explain what I'm doing wrong? I'm pretty sure it has to do something with the memoization but I can't figure out why.

Comment: `memo` should be a `set` or a `dict` depending on the problem, not a `list`.

Comment: `if s in memo: return memo[s]` doesn't make sense for a list.

Comment: X in Y when Y is a list will traverse the whole list while dict and sets use hash tables that can check for inclusion with a single operation

Comment: should all the elements in the `memo` set be present in the broken down word? should any of them overlap?

Comment: Instead of looping the string with different slices and checking the list, I think it makes more sense to just loop the list of words and check `for word in wordDict: if word in s: ...`

Comment: This will likely not help you figure out what you're doing wrong, but this code is instantaneous for your `aaaa...b` example: `def helper(longword, dico, candidates): return (longword in candidates) or (candidates and helper(longword, dico, set(w+c for w in dico for c in candidates if len(w) + len(c) <= len(longword) and w+c in lw)))` `def can_be_broken(longword, dico): return bool(helper(longword, dico, dico)) or len(longword) == 0`